# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have 6 tables in an sqlite database and I'm trying to add a new row in one of the tables using sqlalchemy. Here is my tables:

```
class DSource(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dsource'

    source_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    subjects= relationship("Subject") 

class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subject'

    subject_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    source_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("dsource.source_id"),nullable=False)
    sequences= relationship("Sequence")

class Sequence(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'sequence'

     sequence_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     subject_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("subject.subject_id"),nullable=False)
```

Here is the code I'm using to add a new sequence to the table:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:////Desktop/emotion_data/test.db',echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

new_sequence=Sequence(sequence_id=0,subject_id=1)
session.add(new_sequence)
session.commit()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subject_id'
```

I have no idea what does that mean, I already have imported a "subject" instance with "subject_id=0" to the table, so the subject_id=0 is already in the database.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I also should mention that the definition of tables and the code I'm using to add a new sequence are in different python files. I have imported the above classes prior to calling session.add(). If I put these all together in one python file, it works fine with no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, if the exception only raises when your split your source to different files. There must be something like name conflict, `Sequence` class may not be what you expected, you can check this by prepending those lines before the init process.

```
print Sequence.__module__
print type(Sequence)
```

Comment: Thank you!
I tried the the above code, and here is the result: 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors.VisitableType'>'

Comment: It was exactly a name conflict, I change the class name "Sequence" to something else and every thing works fine now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2308191aha, `Sequence` is the name which sqlalchemy is using. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence